# Consumer sync in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am having the 100 clients will push the  data to the rabbit mq. In the rabbit mq I am using direct exchange to push in to the queue. In the rabbit mq side i am using 10 consumers to consumer with the pre-fetch. So its consuming the data and processing properly.

But i want to make some logic needs to apply in the consumer side where "One consumer need to pick same client data alone". For example a client -1 pushed 100 information should be processed by the single consumer alone, its should not get distributed with another consumer.

I can able to set some message properties at the time pushing to rabbit mq. Is there any concept to achieve my use case.

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail how your exchanges and queues are configured? The terms "consumer" and "client" are not clear when we talk about RabbitMQ.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to use routing keys. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html